# How to avoid overlapping divs containg white-space: nowrap property

Tags: html, css, overlapping

I want distribute some links in columns. I use this css:

```
.cols{
    float: left;
    width: 25%; 
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="CRMP_WP_QUICKADS_cols">
    text...
</div>
```

The image show the resulting output:

[image]

How can avoid overlapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solutions:

- You could hide the last part: `overflow: hidden; text-overflow:
  ellipsis;`
- You could increase the width of the divs

Answer (score 1):

Set `overflow` to `hidden` to cutoff any content that exceeds the `width` of the column:

```css
.cols {
 /* ... */
 overflow:hidden;
 text-overflow:ellipsis; /* Hint that some text is hidden */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**3 options**

1. Increase width
2. Remove the width declaration on the divs (if you want them to expand to fit the text)
3. set `overflow: hidden` on the div if you want to hide the text

Answer (score -1):

You must increase the `width` of the columns to compensate for the overflowing text.